# PHP email is not sending emails to few servers

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, azure

I am using this code to send an email

```
$headers = "From: eplatform@wheelers.co.nz";

mail('test@gmail.com', 'My Subject', "test",$headers);
mail('test@abc.com.au', 'My Subject', "test1",$headers);
mail('test@gmail.com', 'My Subject', "test",$headers);
mail('test@xyz.com.au', 'My Subject', "test1",$headers);
```

I am using azure and have setup **Ubuntu** apache and have installed **sendmail**

But I am not able to receive emails to some of domains like **abc.com.au**

Any idea ?

Comment: Can you send mail to Gmail? Google and some others mail service reject mail from some unknown host like that. Message from Google: " Our system has detected that this message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for more information"

Comment: yes i am able to send into Gmail, But not to abc.com.au.

Comment: @Hitu Bansal: have you contacted support at `abc.com.au` to ask them what their requirements are for email delivery?  If email is successfully delivered to one service provider but not another, this indicates the latter service provider has additional rules and restrictions regarding email form and may even use their own sender domain whitelists and whatnot.  Even following [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) doesn't guarantee all service providers will honor your email.

Comment: previously i was getting emails forabc.com.au . But i moved my sever to azure now.  So,  i was supposing this problem occurs on my end.  is it ? or still i need to contact abc.com.au

Comment: @Hitu Bansal: I would still recommend containg abc.com.au tech support, and even asking them finer details of what they require down to line ending characters they require (ie `\r\n` vs `\n`) and specific headers they require (ie "Reply-To" on top of "From").  RFC 2822 is more of a guideline, but email service providers often have their own way of handling the little things.

Comment: ok Thanks i will contact them right away

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: i checked with them . it seems not working from our side. lots of different email doesn't going to different domians . I have moved my domain from one server to another

Comment: I suspect if you check your local mail server logs (assuming you have PHP configured to use it) you will find the mail is being rejected by the recipient's mail server. You should leverage Sendgrid in order to deliver email reliably to recipients as most email blacklists include some or all of AWS and Azure's public address spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:
1. On Azure Ubuntu VM, check /var/log/mail.log, see if the mail is sent out successfully. If you see "verify=FAIL" related to recipient address, the mail is not delivered properly. Make sure the recipient address is correct.
2. From recipient side, see if there is any rule for your sender (from Azure VM), blacklist, junk mail, etc. Public address of your Ubuntu VM on Azure is ".cloudapp.net".